# What are these ADF IR Service URLs?

Tags: azure

> Azure Data Factory Studio > Integration Runtimes > Nodes > Service
> URLs

There's an expected entry for my ADF :

```
adf-dev2.westus3.datafactory.azure.net
```

But then there are hundreds of entries such as :

```
g0-prod-phx10-001-sb.servicebus.windows.net
g0-prod-phx10-002-sb.servicebus.windows.net
```

What are these ?

Comment: The question lags on Information. What is your *business related issue or problem* inhere? More Details might help to assist you, but what research ahve you done which is also required? Please Consider ["how do i ask a good question"](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

For your ADF Self Hosted Integration Runtime (SHIR) to function the corporate firewall must allow connections outbound to that DNS plus others [documented here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#ports-and-firewalls).